# Ajax Request not accessing Controller, Laravel

Tags: ajax, post, laravel-5

I have a simple post request that is currently working if I dont specify a controller in my route file. When I change the route to access a controller I have specifically created for AJAX requests it returns a 500 Internal server error.

My Route.php looks like this:

```
Route::post('ajaxTagStore', 'AjaxController@postAjaxTag');
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
public function postAjaxTag(Request $request) {
  if(Request::ajax()){
    return Response::json(Request::all());
  }
}
```

}

and lastly my AJAX code looks like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tag-btn').click(function(){
    var fname = $('#firstname').val();
    var lname = $('#lastname').val();
    var token = $('#token').val();

    var dataString = $('#tag').serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/ajaxTagStore',
      data: dataString,
      success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
        console.log(response);
        $('#postRequestData').html(response);
      }
    })

  });
});
```

As I said it works if I don't specify a controller and just use this:

```
Route::post('ajaxTagStore', function(){
 if(Request::ajax()){
  return Response::json(Request::all());
 }
});
```

Any suggestions as to why this is? (I am using a csrf-token also)

Comment: Do you have anything error messages in your storage/logs directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 possible problems.

1. Are you create it manually through your text editor or copied from another controller? if so, then I could suggest to `composer dump-autoload` your project so that it will renew its autoloaded files.
2. Laravel's Controller uses different `Request` class than the one used in the `routes.php` file, so I also suggest when you to change `if(Request::ajax()){` to `if($request->ajax()){` in your controller method

Do let me know if one of these solution fixed your problem. If it still having problem, show the error message shown in your ajax result. Hope it answer your question.

Comment: @JoelPierre glad it works, if you find this answer is the solution, just mark this as accepted and don't forget to upvote, thanks!